# Adding dynamic fields into jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I have the following ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'library/test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        id: id, // label id
        field1: field1,
        field2: field2,
        field3: field3,
        field4: field4,
        field5: field5,
        field6: field6,
        field7: field7,
        field8: field8,
        product: product,   
        occasion: occasion
    },
    success: function (res) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

now if an id is equal to 1 lets say i need an extra field in the ajax data. Are you allowed if statements in the data field?
or would i need to construct the array and then input the array into the data? i'm little confussed. What would be the best practice for this?

example:

```
data: {
    id: id, // label id
    field1: field1,
    field2: field2,
    field3: field3,
    field4: field4,
    field5: field5,
    field6: field6,
    field7: field7,
    field8: field8,
    product: product,   
    occasion: occasion
    if (id == 1) { 
       // very much doubt this will even work
       ,do: something
    }
},
```

or even

```
if (id == 1) {
    var array = {"field1": field1, "field2": field2,"do": something};
}
else {
    var array {"field1": field1, "field2": field2};
}
data: { 
    //obviously this would be in the ajax function
    array
}
```

would this work? what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional operators.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'library/test.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {
    id: id, // label id
    field1: field1,
    field2: field2,
    field3: field3,
    field4: field4,
    field5: ((id == 1) ? field5 : "default field5"),
    field6: field6,
    field7: field7,
    field8: field8,
    product: product,   
    occasion: occasion
},
success: function (res) {
    //do something
}
```

If it's getting complex and you want it to be more readible, you can assign arrays as you've shown.

For example:

```
var dataArray;

if (id == 1) {
    dataArray = {
        id: id, // label id
        field1: field1,
        field2: field2,
    };
}
else {
    dataArray = {
        id: id, // label id
        field4: field4,
        field6: field6,
        field7: field7,
    };
}

$.ajax({
url: 'library/test.php',
type: 'POST',
data: dataArray,
success: function (res) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer, the only reason i have avoided this is because in most cases the "field5" field isn't needed at all only by 4 out of the 40 cases

Comment: It's not advisable not to send it at all. Just send null instead. Also I've edited the answer to be more detailed

Comment: perfect, the second one is, i think the best option. Thank you for your help.

Comment: don't worry i was eventually going to do it. Just when i tried to accept originally it was under the 7 minutes